# Installing multiqc on Conda produces "UnsatisfiableError:"

Tags: python, unix, conda

I have tried installing a program called multiqc and it throws this error when I try to install it in my conda environment, I have tried to install alternative version of python contained in the list but it doesn't appear to be working.

The command

```
conda install -c bioconda multiqc
```

The install

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                            \
```

And finally the error

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - multiqc -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|3.4.*']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

Comment: How did you try to install an alternative version of python? Your error suggests that you are using 3.7 which seems to be incompatible with the package

Comment: Always, always try creating a new environment: `conda create -n mynewenv -c bioconda multiqc` and add any other packages you need on the same line after `multiqc`. conda will figure out what's compatible.

Comment: This command, (Ref. :https://multiqc.info/docs/), `conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge multiqc ` works for me under "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" and "conda-4.8.3". Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The command to install MultiQC should *not* use `-c bioconda`. Instead, set up the conda channels as per the [bioconda documentation](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) and install without the `-c` flag:

```sh
# Only need to do this once
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge

# Install MultiQC
conda install multiqc
```

If you prefer, you can also install from PyPI or multiple other sources: https://multiqc.info/docs/#installing-multiqc

MultiQC works and is tested on Python 3.6-3.9 at the time of writing. 3.7 should definitely work, so that's not the issue.